# Finding a homomorphism from $T(n,F)$, to $(F^*)^n$ with kernel $UT(n,F)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I’m looking for a homomorphism from the set of upper $n$x$n$ triangular matrices with coefficients from the field $F$, which we call $T(n,F)$, to $(F^*)^n$ with kernel $UT(n,F)$. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: I assume $UT$ means strictly upper triangular?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff:  I think here $UT$ is upper triangular with $1$s on the main diagonal; the *strictly upper triangular* matrices don't form a group; but you knew that, right? 

Comment: I'm not sure how to give a hint without just saying the answer. Perhaps consider the 1, 2, and 3 dimensional cases and working out the cosets of the kernel and see if you can find certain distinguished elements in the cosets (that would perhaps have $n$ nonzero entries)? Hopefully that hint wasn't too strong.

Comment: I don't even know what the homomorphism is going to be >.<

Edit: Ooooh, projection, haha, duh